# How to modify functionality (skip song, play, pause) with side phone volume keys?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, tasker, volume-control, media-player

This is a really requested feature in a lot of forum, but I haven't found any convincing solution.

I'd like that my volume keys:

- If simple (short) press both together, pause/play.
- If simple (short) press of single key, change the volume up or down.
- If pressed and hold change track forward or backward.

My options in order from preferred to less preferred are:

1. Do it with Tasker
2. Download an app to achieve this (not a media player)
3. Develop an app to achieve this (any advice?)
4. Download a media player that has mentioned functionality.

Thanks, Diego

**Note:** With volume keys I don't mean keys in the headphone, I mean those which are at the side of the phone.

Comment: PowerAmp (http://powerampapp.com/) is open source, so that may serve as a good starting point.

Comment: What's the sense of a paid app which lets you unlock it for free? Also: where can I find the source code?.. You can post this as an answer.. I think it will end up resolving my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PowerAmp](http://powerampapp.com/) is an open source app, which may serve as a good starting point for developing your own app.  The code can be found [here](http://powerampapp.com/oss/).

Answer (score 1):

Headset button controller is an excellent app in market which will do all these functions..

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kober.headsetbutton&feature=more_from_developer

Comment: While that does look like a useful app, the OP is looking for something that changes the behavior of the buttons on the device itself.